# Sending POST via CURL error

Tags: bash, curl, terminal

I am trying to send a HTTP POST via CURL on the command line. I am doing something wrong. Could someone advise me on what's wrong with my command? I am doing the following:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://www.url-here.com -d {JSON OBJECT HERE}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add -v you'll get a verbose error message, could help with debugging.

According to the [manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), you should put options before the url.

This is a curl call I'm using for testing at the moment, which work just fine:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{}' http://example.com
```